# How to make an ifelse statement ignore NAs?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, data-wrangling

Hello I have this code

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(prev_PC = ifelse(changed_PC  == "No" & (is.na(prev_PC) | prev_PC == ""), new_PC, prev_PC))
```

I'm trying to change the previous postal code. Let's say we have old postal codes and we have new postal codes.

The old postal codes are from a smaller dataset that overlaps with a bigger dataset that has new postal codes. In the same dataset as the old ones ones we have a variable that says no or yes if people changed their postal code (the questionnaire about the old postal codes are asked after the questionnare with the new ones).

I want to use this variable to fill in old postal codes with the new postal codes if they did not change their postal codes. However, since there are about a 1000 NA values in the changed_PC variable, it fills the prev_PC with NAs in those cases, and I am left with more NAs in prev_PC than before. How can I change this?

TL;DR: I want the changed_PC  == "No" if statement to ignore NAs. So if changed_PC == NA, I just want it to keep the value in prev_PC as if it said "Yes" instead of making the prev_PC into a NA.

Here is an example:

```
prev_PC <- c(5039, 1402, 3050, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
new_PC <- c(5039, 1402, 3050, 3021, 2154, 4853, 1252, 2954)
changed_PC <- c("No", NA, "No", "Yes", NA, NA, "No", "No")

df <- data.frame(prev_PC , new_PC, changed_PC )
```

What I want:

```
prev_PC 
5039, 1402, 3050, NA, NA, NA, 1252, 2954
```

What I get:

```
prev_PC
5039, NA, 3050, NA, NA, NA, 1252, 2954
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten It's unfortunately sensitive data. I'm not sure how to create a minimally reproducible sample in a smaller format.

Comment: Even if it is sensitive data, it is up to you, to provide a dataset that encompasses the problem that you are facing.

Comment: You're trying to do a join, and specifically a join that doesn't care about ambiguities on one of the variables. I'd make a look-up data-frame for the postal codes, maybe using `dplyr::distinct` or `dplyr::slice`.. And use that to do a `dplyr::left_join`.

Comment: @Quinten, I updated the code to have a dataset.

Comment: @Mossa see extra code now. I am not trying to join as they are already joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution looks like:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(prev_PC = case_when(changed_PC == "No" &
                               is.na(prev_PC) ~ new_PC,
                             TRUE ~ prev_PC))
```

but this is probably better:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(prev_PC = if_else(is.na(prev_PC) & 
                               changed_PC == "No", new_PC, prev_PC))
```

Resulting in:

```r
> df %>% 
+   print() %>% 
+   mutate(prev_PC = if_else(is.na(prev_PC) & 
+                                changed_PC == "No", new_PC, prev_PC))
  prev_PC new_PC changed_PC
1    5039   5039         No
2    1402   1402       <NA>
3    3050   3050         No
4      NA   3021        Yes
5      NA   2154       <NA>
6      NA   4853       <NA>
7      NA   1252         No
8      NA   2954         No
  prev_PC new_PC changed_PC
1    5039   5039         No
2    1402   1402       <NA>
3    3050   3050         No
4      NA   3021        Yes
5      NA   2154       <NA>
6      NA   4853       <NA>
7    1252   1252         No
8    2954   2954         No
```

(see the before and after)

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I have? How can I get more NAs in prev_PC than before when doing this?

Comment: Thank you. You provided the right solution. It somehow doesn't work on my larger dataset (my amount of NAs in the prev_PC are bigger in the after scenario for some reason), so the problem must be different.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to assign df back? `df <- df %>% mutate( [redacted]`?? I'm sorry it wasn't sufficient. 
I answered the question, so I'd appreciate an answered marking.

Comment: yes sorry. I realise that I had a lot of empty fields in prev_PC (not NA but "") and some of these got replaced by NAs which increased the number of NAs in prev_PC. I interpreted this as it was removing data, but using the head() function, I was able to inspect a bit closer.